# How to order a custom post type by a custom datetime picker?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to order a list of events by closest date to the user. I am using a datetime picker using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

But, the events seem to be rendering by the post date instead of the custom datetime picker I have created.

This is a Wordpress Application that is using Timber for the templating engine.

```
        $context['events'] = Timber::get_posts(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'event',
                'order'     => 'ASC',
                'order_by'  => 'date_and_time_of_event',
            )
        );
```

The expected result is that the page renders the events list by the `date_and_time_of_event` and shows the date nearest to the user first.

But I think that the events list is rendering using the `post_date` instead of the required `date_and_time_of_event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array(
            'post_type'   => 'event',
            'meta_key'    => 'date_and_time_of_event',
            'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
            'order'       => 'ASC',

     )
```

Try this